# Write a big file using vertx

Tags: vert.x

I am using vertx websocket. I am sending  a big file through it. What's the best way to use filesystem? Async filesystem might not work properly if multiple frames are arriving at the same file. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are sending a file in multiple parts, and you want to ensure that your file is written in the correct order.

You should provide a way to identify which part you are receiving (a header), and store the parts somewhere (maybe each part in its own file, and store the metadata in a concurrent priority queue) and then reassemble the parts (pumping from the queue). You can start writing the result file as long as you have the first part received, and continue while you have the next part available.

I hope this will help.